# Align \itemize and \tabular horizontally

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, lists

I have an `\itemize` list and a `\tabular` table, how do I get them to align horizontally on the the same line? This is what I have so far:

```
\documentclass[8pt, a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, comment, array}
\usepackage[cm]{fullpage}

\begin{document}

\begin {itemize}
    \item \begin{math} P[S] = 1\end{math}
    \item \begin{math} \{ \forall A \in S  : P[A] \ge 0 \} \end{math}
    \item \begin{math} P[\varnothing] = 0 \end{math}
    \item \begin{math} P[A'] = 1 - P[A] \end{math}
\end {itemize}

\begin{tabular} {| p{3cm} | p{6cm} | }  
\hline
    General Addition Rule & \begin{math} P[A_1\cup A_2] = P[A_1] + P[A_2] - P[A_1 \cap A_2] \end{math} \\ \hline
    Conditional Probability & \begin{math} P[A_2|A_1] = \frac {P[A_1 \cap A_2]} {P[A_1]} \end{math} \\ \hline
    Independent Events &\begin{math} P[ \displaystyle \bigcap_{A \in S} A] = \prod_{A \in S} P[A] \end{math} \\ \hline
    Multiplication Rule & \begin{math} P[A_1 \cap A_2] = P[A_2|A_1]P[A_1] \end{math} \\ \hline
    Bayes' Theorem & \begin{math} P[A_j|B] = \frac {P[B|A_j]P[A_j]} {\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n P[B|A_i]P[A_i]} \end{math} \\ \hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to put the list in a minipage. Also there is no `8pt` option.

[image]

```
\documentclass[pa4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, comment, array}
\usepackage[cm]{fullpage}

\begin{document}

\noindent X\dotfill X


\noindent
\begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}
\begin {itemize}
    \item \begin{math} P[S] = 1\end{math}
    \item \begin{math} \{ \forall A \in S  : P[A] \ge 0 \} \end{math}
    \item \begin{math} P[\varnothing] = 0 \end{math}
    \item \begin{math} P[A'] = 1 - P[A] \end{math}
\end {itemize}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\begin{tabular} {| p{3cm} | p{6cm} | }  
\hline
    General Addition Rule & \begin{math} P[A_1\cup A_2] = P[A_1] + P[A_2] - P[A_1 \cap A_2] \end{math} \\ \hline
    Conditional Probability & \begin{math} P[A_2|A_1] = \frac {P[A_1 \cap A_2]} {P[A_1]} \end{math} \\ \hline
    Independent Events &\begin{math} P[ \displaystyle \bigcap_{A \in S} A] = \prod_{A \in S} P[A] \end{math} \\ \hline
    Multiplication Rule & \begin{math} P[A_1 \cap A_2] = P[A_2|A_1]P[A_1] \end{math} \\ \hline
    Bayes' Theorem & \begin{math} P[A_j|B] = \frac {P[B|A_j]P[A_j]} {\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n P[B|A_i]P[A_i]} \end{math} \\ \hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much!